# Display number of lines instead of cart total count woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce, shopping-cart

Instead of the total quantity of the products, I want to display the number of lines in my minicart icon.

I've made/found this piece of code, but it gives an error. I've tried multiple versions. Anybody know how to fix my code?

Thanks

```
get_cart_contents_count ( '<p> Line cart items count: ' . count( WC()->cart_get_cart() ) . '</p>' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Is fixed!

For anybody with the same question:

}`function woolunatic_alter_cart_contents_count( $count ) { $count = count( WC()->cart->get_cart() ); return $count; }`